# How to open all links in chrome custom tabs

Tags: android, google-chrome, textview, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm trying to make an activity which has a few TextViews which in turn,contain hyperlinks. I did this using this tutorial: http://www.android-examples.com/add-hyperlink-in-android-application-through-textview/

I want to make these links open up in chrome custom tabs when they are clicked(similar to Gmail). But I cant find any tutorial that shows how to do so.

Comment: get the data from text view and parse with uri. u can not able to parse uri i will give code tell me.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it by extending the `URLSpan` and overriding the `onClick` method.Here's a gist that contains a sample implementation: https://gist.github.com/andreban/b809ba40454091845dd5